# How to do a htacces rewrite rule with exceptions?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I am trying to do a rewrite rule from

```
http://website.com/location/new-york.php <- user goes to
```

to

```
http://website.com/location/city.php?name=new-york <- u use this in my code
```

and depending on the rewrite rule I think i need a exception for

```
http://website.com/location/city.php...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to create exception in this rule for .htaccess in `/location/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /location/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!city\.php$)(.+?)(?:\.php)?$ city.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: can I have multiple `RewriteBase` entries? I already have some stuff int eh htaccess file, including `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Is your .htaccess located in site root (a level above `location`) and is that only .htaccess?

Comment: yeah, is in the root. then a `location` folder

Comment: ok if `location` folder already has a .htaccess then above rule must be placed in `/location/.htaccess` only

Comment: by the way, if i wanted to make the `.php` in `/new-york.php` optional... how would the rule look like?